# Changing default seekbar color

Tags: android, colors, seekbar

If anybody knows what i'm doing wrong please let me know. 
I created an android app and I am trying to change the default color of the seekbar from yellow to any other color. I created an xml file located in all 3 drawables and ran the project but the color of the seekbar still isnt changing color.
Below is the code me and a fellow mate from irc have been working on.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
>
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#FF0000"
                android:centerColor="#FF0000"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#FF0000"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

This is my java code

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekbarvalue);       //filling seekbar 
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
            {

                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress+1998));  //sets the date to seekBar when in motion
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {
                //TO DO Auto-Generated Method stub  
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {
                //TO DO Auto-Generated Method stub
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't show where the XML is used. Please post relevant code in the thread

Comment: Please edit your question (DO NOT START A THIRD QUESTION) and show where you are using this drawable to customize your `SeekBar`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing yellow default seekbar color.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315641/changing-yellow-default-seekbar-color)

Comment: This has been marked as an exact duplicate of your other question, that is a copy off this, I'll edit to make sure any changes match.

Comment: Use seekbar.setProgressDrawable() to set progress color

Answer (score 4):

Okay so basically all i needed to do is go into my main.xml file not the one located in the drawables folder and then make sure to put

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/myprogress"
```

where myprogress is the name of my .xml file located in the drawables folder.