# How To Change Seek bar Color in Android?

Tags: android

I'm just wondering if the seekbar changed in Android 2.1 . I tried to create one but it showing up as a green line with a circle on it instead of the usual yellow rectangle. If so, is there any other option to create a similar seekbar to control volume on 2.1? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314488/changing-default-seekbar-color

Comment: I have used this for customize seekbar in android 2.1 and it worked well. http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/ you can also have look at these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480456/seek-bar-change-path-color-from-yellow-to-white http://www.anddev.org/seekbar_progressbar_customizing-t6083.html